# Cache lookup failed for function 1 while enabling postgis on postgres 10

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to enable PostGIS on a PostgreSQL 10 database on Windows. Earlier it used to work fine, but now I am getting an error 'cache lookup failed for function 1' on enabling the extension.

I am using pgAdmin to do it and have tried shell also. I reinstalled PostGIS from StackBuilder also.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you yet no solution was found to resolve it. I'm wondering if you did succeed to find it out?

Comment: no!  i just installed postgres again and it works

Comment: That what I did too

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by incorrectly configured system settings or irregular entries in the Windows registry.Extensions aren't necessarily supported, the underlying disk files for extensions may have changed.

Try checking that.

I suppose you would have used a big query or something like that.